# QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS - problems with dependencies between header files

Tags: c++, qt, bison, qmake, flex-lexer

I am creating a Qt project using flex and bison. There is a dependency between the header file `_CMPL_Parser.hh` (generated by bison) and the header file `compile.hh` (`#include _CMPL_Parser.hh`).

I use `QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS` to include flex and bison in my project (see the part of my project file below). Unfortunately, `_CMPL_Parser.hh` is created after the compiler needs this file to include it in `compiler.hh -> compiler.cc`.

```
...

FLEX_SOURCES = src/cmpl/CMPL_Scanner.l
BISON_SOURCES = src/cmpl/CMPL_Parser.yy

flex.commands=flex -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
flex.output= $$OUT_PWD/_CMPL_Scanner.cc
flex.input=FLEX_SOURCES
flex.variable_out=SOURCES
flex.name=flex ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS+=flex

bisonsource.commands=bison -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
bisonsource.output= $$OUT_PWD/_CMPL_Parser.cc
bisonsource.input=BISON_SOURCES
bisonsource.variable_out=SOURCES
bisonsource.name=bisonsource ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS+=bisonsource

bisonheader.commands=@true
bisonheader.output= $$OUT_PWD/_CMPL_Parser.hh
bisonheader.input=BISON_SOURCES
bisonheader.variable_out=HEADERS
bisonheader.name=bisonheader ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
#bisonheader.depends= bin/_CMPL_Parser.cc
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS+=bisonheader

...

HEADERS += src/cmpl/Compiler.hh \
           src/cmpl/FileIO.hh \
     ...

SOURCES += src/cmpl/Compiler.cc \
           src/cmpl/FileIO.cc \
       ...
```

I also tried to define the following dependencies in my project file. But it failed, too.

```
chh.input = src/cmpl/Compiler.hh
chh.depends = $$OUT_PWD/_CMPL_Parser.hh
chh.name = chh
chh.dependency_type = TYPE_C
chh.variable_out = HEADERS
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += chh
```

How is it possible to express that `_CMPL_Parser.hh` is to be created before it is be used by other files?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to what to put at the end of chh.depends?

Answer (score 2):

1. QMake already comes with a lex/yacc integration that uses flex on all platforms, as far as I can see. So for flex, just say:

   ```
   CONFIG += lex
   LEXSOURCES += src/cmpl/CMPL_Scanner.l
   ```
2. QMake indeed doesn't support bison out of the box. But seeing as yacc and bison are basically the same, I'd try something like the following:

   ```
   QMAKE_YACC=bison
   # maybe adjust some other QMAKE_YACC* variables
   CONFIG += yacc    
   YACCSOURCES += src/cmpl/CMPL_Parser.yy
   ```
3. In addition, if you run into problems where the compile job is running before the bison job has finished (a qmake bug, it seems), you should use this workaround:

   ```
   lex.CONFIG += target_predeps
   yacc_impl.CONFIG += target_predeps
   yacc_decl.CONFIG += target_predeps
   ```

   This will force the outputs of each of these QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS to be a dependency of the (main) target, effectively ensuring that the generated files are available before compilation starts.